# Oracle table partition not working

Tags: sql, oracle11g, create-table, database-partitioning

I am new to the oracle database and I create a partitioned table and insert some date into it but the data are not partitioned.

Table:

```
Create Table Buclm_Adapterdb.zzzz
(
   Id     Number   
)
Partition By Range (Id)
(  
   Partition T1 Values Less Than (100),
   Partition T2 Values Less Than (maxvalue)
)
;
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO Buclm_Adapterdb.zzzz (id) VALUES (50);
INSERT INTO Buclm_Adapterdb.zzzz (id) VALUES (150);
INSERT INTO Buclm_Adapterdb.zzzz (id) VALUES (250);
```

Data are inserted:

[image]

However, data are not partitioned, Num Rows are empty:

[image]

Why?

Comment: You only created two partitions. What did you expect?

Comment: T1 should have 1 row (50), T2 should have 2 rows (150, 250), that is what i expect ? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Where does that `num_rows` come from? If that is from `user_tables.num_rows` then you need to update the statistics first using the `dbms_stats` package

Comment: ok..... @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to gather statistics to see the NUM_ROWS updated:

`dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( ownname => 'Buclm_Adapterdb', tabname => 'zzzz');`

Read up here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68600